# Expanding coordinates of a variable using other two variables of xarray in Python

Tags: python, python-xarray

Let's say I have data of 16 grid cells (4 * 4) which has a corresponding index (0~15) as dimension & coordinates and variables (**a**, **longitude** and **latitude**) for each cell. Here is the code to create this data.

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(16,3), \
                  columns=['a','longitude', 'latitude'], \
                  index=range(16))
ds = df.to_xarray()
ds
```

What I want to do is:

Expand the coordination of data **a** from (**index**) to (**longitude**, **latitude**) using **longitude** and **latitude** variables of each cell.
So, the resulting DataSet will include **longitude** and **latitude** as its dimension and coordinates as well as variable **a** of (**longitude**, **latitude**)
How can I do this within xarray functionality?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to solve that:

```
# convert the index as a MultiIndex containing longitude and latitude
dat_2d = ds.set_index({'index': ['longitude', 'latitude']})

# unstack the MultiIndex
unstacked = dat_2d.unstack('index')

# plot
unstacked['a'].plot()
```